# Changing keyboard shortcut

Tags: javascript, keyboard-shortcuts

during my everyday work I must send a lot of e-mails using one platform, which has a default keyboard shortcut to trigger an e-mail prompt which is "CTRL+ALT+M".

Although, I would prefer doing this shortcut with one hand, and reaching "M" is not that easy, so is there a way to make it so that pressing "CTRL+ALT+X" would trigger "CTRL+ALT+M"?

In other words, I want that pressing "CTRL+ALT+X" would open an e-mail prompt and there is no option tho change the shortcut in this website.

[image: default e-mail prompt opening shortcut]

I've already tried using "Shortcuts" chrome extension, but for some reason it doesn't work :/

[image]

This also doesn't work

Also tried this, doesn't work

```
  {
    "key": "ctrl+alt+x",
    "action": "trigger",
    "trigger": "ctrl+alt+m",
    "sites": "",
    "sitesArray": [
      ""
    ]
  }
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can dispatch a new `KeyboardEvent` that sends a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> programatically.

```js
const sendOffer = () => alert('New email!');

// Original binding Ctrl + Alt + M (cannot modify)
document.addEventListener('keydown', (keyEvent) => {
  if (keyEvent.code === 'KeyM' && keyEvent.altKey && keyEvent.ctrlKey) {
    sendOffer(); // Internal handler logic in application
  }
});

// New binding Ctrl + Alt + X (alias)
document.addEventListener('keydown', (keyEvent) => {
  if (keyEvent.code === 'KeyX' && keyEvent.altKey && keyEvent.ctrlKey) {
    // If Ctrl + Alt + X it pressed, send Ctrl + Alt + M
    document.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keydown', {
      code: 'KeyM',
      altKey: true,
      ctrlKey: true
    }));
  }
  keyEvent.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<button
    onclick="sendOffer()"
    title="Send offer by e-mail [Ctrl+Alt+m]">
  Open in new tab
</button>
```

The second half of the example above can be thrown into a userscript (Violentmonkey, Greasemonkey, etc...) and executed on the webpage where the key is needed.

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name        Custom keybindings for company website
// @namespace   Violentmonkey Scripts
// @match       https://my-company-website.com/*
// @grant       none
// @version     1.0
// ==/UserScript==
(() => {
  // New binding Ctrl + Alt + X (alias)
  document.addEventListener('keydown', (keyEvent) => {
    if (keyEvent.code === 'KeyX' && keyEvent.altKey && keyEvent.ctrlKey) {
      // If Ctrl + Alt + X it pressed, send Ctrl + Alt + M
      document.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keydown', {
        code: 'KeyM',
        altKey: true,
        ctrlKey: true
      }));
    }
    keyEvent.preventDefault();
  });
})();
```

**Note:** The [following website](https://www.toptal.com/developers/keycode) is helpful for diagnosing keyboard events.

If you are still confused, see the [documentation on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/code).